# Addressing Multiple IBOutlets within a Loop

Tags: swift

I have 3 IBOutlets, defined as:

- imageView1
- imageView2
- imageView3

I would like to specify each IBOutlet within a loop.

```
for (index, item) in items {
    imageView + index.image = UIImage()
}
```

It would seem some form of string interpolation is required?

Comment: let images = [imageView1, imageView2, imageView3] and then use images in for loop?

Comment: Variables are evaluated at compile time. Any *form of string interpolation is* **not** supported.

Comment: Variables don't even exist at runtime. They're convenient memnotics created just for human understanding. They're one of the first things stripped out during compilation, just like comments.

Comment: thanks for directing to a similar question. using the same "outlet collection" method creates an array of imageView's that I can use in the suggested loop above with imageViewCollection[index].image = ...